# Setting up a watchguard policy to allow sharepoint site access from the internet

Tags: sharepoint, firewall, wss-3.0, watchguard

I have a sharepoint site that I have full access to over the local network, but from the internet I just get webpage can not be displayed. I've checked the settings in IIS and Sharepoint and everything looks fine. This leads me to believe that our firewall is blocking traffic. I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction in making a policy for watchguard to allow internet traffic to sharepoint sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what model Watchguard firewall you have and what management software you're running, this is probably the best place to start:

http://www.watchguard.com/help/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that the server is configured to use the watchguard as the default gateway?